# Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

Tags: excel, vba

After browsing Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library from Tools/Reference and seeing it on the list, but in action it hasn't installed and I can't see it again in the list.

Comment: Writing in ALL CAPS is annoying, because it's very hard to read, and it's generally considered **SHOUTING** at your audience, which is just plain rude - **don't do it** and fix your post here ASAP!

Comment: You need to add the controls into the controls toolbox. In the forms designer, pick the last icon on the toolbox to make controls available for forms design.